# Show quantity and percent values on Chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I everyone;

I'm working with a ASP NET Chart and I have one Column Chart. In this chart I want to show the values of percent and quantity like '10% (100)'.
I did it and it's working, but the column is shown based on percent value but I want to base it on quantity value.
This is my code:

```
Series mainSeries = new Series(serieName);
mainSeries.XValueMember = "ANSWER";
mainSeries.YValueMembers = "Total";
mainSeries.Label = "#PERCENT" + "\n(#VALY)";
```

This is the problem. I want that the size of the column is shown based in percent value and in this way the column size is based on quantity value.
If I change the YValueMembers by "Percent" when I have quantity equal 100 and percent equal 10, the value is shown like '10% (10)', I mean...just the percent value is shown.

That is my chart, I would like to show the column based in 50% not in 1 (quantity).

[image]

Any idea about how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this can help

```
 Chart.Series[0].Points.DataBind(dv, "PKProject", "TotalSale", "LegendText=ProjectLabel");
 ChartSalesPerProject.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";
```

Comment: Hey, I tryed to do it but it isn't working how I expected! The "LegendText" is not shown correctly.